# How do I get Pandas Matplotlib graphs to load?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

How I can load these data frame graphs (see code below)?

I can load the graphs no problem in Jupyter Notebook with %matplotlib inline.

However when I go to Idle and Command Line Prompt they don't load. I have stripped out %matplotlib inline as I am aware that is a Jupyter Notebook command.

I have tried **plt.show()** which usually works and **df.plot.show()**

I feel I am forgetting or missing something very basic. This is the first time I have tried to do graphs from Data Frames.

```
df.plot(kind='bar')


df.plot(kind='barh')

df.plot.pie(y='ItemsOrdered', figsize=(5, 5))

df.plot.pie(y='Transactions', figsize=(5, 5))


#https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

df.plot.pie(y='AIV', figsize=(5, 5))


df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(11, 6))


df.plot.bar(subplots=True, figsize=(11, 6))


df.plot.barh(subplots=True, figsize=(11, 6))
```

Comment: Have you imported matplotlib.pyplot?

Comment: Yes. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt , I am not sure where to go with it as the df.plot seems to be handling the plotting commands and the plt.show() isn't activating graphs to appear

Comment: plt.savefig("plots.png") works

Comment: That's strange that the plot won't show, but will save. Glad you figured it out though.